# How can i develop for shopware 5 on a windows system?

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp, shopware

The actual shopware 5 is not working on a windows system (win7) with xampp (5.6.3).
It installs correctly, front- and backend are ok, but if you like to do any procedure which saves data to the mysql database (especially to open a new admin user account in the backend) there is no data entry.
On a linux system it works perfectly.

Comment: And would you like to further elaborate on "it is not working"? Do you get a specific error message, or does your computer just melt into a pile of plastic and metal?

Comment: no error message, no other problems, just no data entry in mysql.

Comment: i have a german version. in the backend preferences under logfiles i find the entry that the user was successfully updated and i had to clean the cache and login again. i did that but nothing happened. and there is no data entry in the s_core_auth mysql table

Comment: and  i don't think it is a bug of my system because it works well with other applications like magento etc. ...

Comment: Please note that shopware 5 is not supported on windows. It's recommended to develop on linux/unix based system. You can use a preconfigured vagrant box for that: https://github.com/shopwareLabs/shopware-vagrant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on a Windows System the best way would be to install a Virtual Machine.

Shopware has already a working Vagrant Repo to install Shopware 5 with Vagrant within minutes.

[Check out the DOC here](https://devdocs.shopware.com/developers-guide/vagrant-phpstorm/)